# Order by newly selected column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a query like:

```
SELECT 
    R.*     
FROM 
    (SELECT A, B, 
            (SELECT smth from another table) as C,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC) AS RowNumber 
     FROM SomeTable) R
WHERE 
     RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

This gives me an error on `ORDER BY C DESC`.

I understand why this error is caused, so I've thought of adding another `SELECT` with `ORDER BY` and only than selecting rows from 10 to 20. But I don't think it's good to have 3 nested `SELECT` commands.

How else is it possible to select these rows?

Comment: I understand the subquery producing `C` is correlated with the one where you are trying to generate row numbers. If that is so, you could try transforming the correlated subquery into one you could join to. (My guess is you would simply need to use the correlation condition as a join condition, but I can't be sure without seeing the subquery and how it is related to other parts of the entire query.)

Comment: The subquery is selecting count from another table with some siple condition.

Comment: `… (SELECT s.A, s.B, a.C, ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY a.C DESC) FROM SomeTable s INNER JOIN (SELECT Key, COUNT(*) AS C FROM AnotherTable) a ON s.Key = c.Key) R …`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column cannot refer to an alias on same level, you have to table-derive it first, or use CTE.

```
SELECT 
    R.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC) AS RowNumber     
FROM 
    (SELECT A, B, (SELECT smth from another table) as C
     FROM SomeTable) R
-- WHERE 
     -- but you still cannot do this
     -- RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Need to do this:

```
select S.*
from
(
    SELECT 
        R.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC) AS RowNumber     
    FROM 
        (SELECT A, B, 
                (SELECT smth from another table) as C
         FROM SomeTable) R
) as s
where s.RowNumber between 10 and 20
```

To avoid deep nesting and to make it at least look pleasant, use CTE:

```
with R as
(
     SELECT A, B, (SELECT smth from another table) as C
     FROM SomeTable
)
,S AS 
(
    SELECT R.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM R
)
SELECT S.*
FROM S
WHERE S.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aliased columns in the same `SELECT`, but you can wrap it into another select to make it work:

```
SELECT R.*
FROM (SELECT ABC.A, ABC.B, ABC.C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C DESC) AS RowNumber
      FROM (SELECT A, B, (SELECT smth from another table) as C FROM SomeTable) ABC 
) R
WHERE R.RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure that I got the parentheses balanced correctly, but I hope this gives you enough information to make it work.

Comment: Actually this is the 3 nested selects which I was trying to avoid, but thanks anyway )))